# Font Awesome spinners icons not spinning

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to add a [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) [spinner icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#spinner) to a page when I click a button using Jquery, however the spinners does not actually spin.

http://codepen.io/Riggster/pen/WvLZxb

```
<li id="num1">
  <p>1:
    PHP Code for random number here
  </p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="NewNum()" type="button">Re-roll random numbers</button>
  </p>
</li>

function NewNum() {
  $("#num1").html("<i class='fa fa-refresh'></i>");
}
```

Comment: Explanation on how to make it work: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/animating-icons

Answer (score 56, accepted):

adding fa-spin to the class like this will work:

```
function NewNum() {
  $("#num1").html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i>");
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Another thing to note with `fa-spin` is it won't work on a `display: inline` element.

It needs to be `display: inline-block` or `display: block`

Answer (score 9):

**Alert!!!**

Sometimes, even if the code is fine, your pc settings may be the culprit.

Make sure to on animation if you are in windows to actually see any form of animation to work.
You can change the setting in following ways if you are in windows.

**1. search for show animation in windows**
[image]

**2. Scroll down and there you see a radio button for showing animations or not.**
[image]

> Blockquote

Comment: This answer is totally underrated! I had the same problem! I just turned this setting on (I don't know why it was turned off...) and it worked instantly! Thanks! +1

Comment: wow! would've never thought of this. thanks, it's what worked for me

Comment: I am having an existential crisis

Answer (score 1):

```
function NewNum(){
  $("#num1").html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'/>");
}
```

you can refer more font-awesome examples from here

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/spinner/

Comment: It is not enough to make it spin - also need fa-spin. See here: http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated

Answer (score -1):

You try to
Setting -> select Control Panel > System and Security > System > tab Advanced -> Performance -> Settings...
and check 2 box **Animate controls and elements inside windows** and **Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing**